# How to make the address got from google places api clickable?

Tags: android, google-maps, onclick, google-places-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to connect the text view to a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473242/how-to-connect-the-text-view-to-a-website)

Hi i have developed an app which uses google places api to display a list of department stores near the users location.

Now i want to make the list of addresses i get clickable ie; when the user clicks on the name of the department store then i want the android app to go to another activity which accesses the department stores website to get the recommended or discount products in that particular store.

I searched on the net but did not find any tutorials to do this.

Comment: First, refer to [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/) and it will be useful to you.

Comment: Hi i have referred to that tutorial what i want to do is sice the text is generated dynamically ie; in real time i need to make it clickable. Do you know how to do this??

Comment: As you know, you can not handle the data that you got through  Google places API, as you want to do. To handle that date as you want, you must parse the lists in the code of your app and then you can do what you want(go to another activity) when users choose one of the lists. Do you want to use all data (name of the department store) retrieved by Google Place API ?

Comment: No only the Name when i click on it i need to go to the website and display the offers there.