# How to connect the text view to a website?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

Hi i am new to android and i have created a app which uses the google places api and lists a few department stores.

I have made the list clickable upon clicking the name of the department store i am starting a new activity which accesses a database that i created to give the recommended or discount products in that particular store.

What i need is that when i click on the name of the department store i want the app to redirect to the stores website and list all the recommended or discount products in that particular store.

Comment: i am following the following tutorial  http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/  @Shivan Raptor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            String url=urls[position];
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Here you have to place all department urls in a seperate array called `urls`

Comment: Hi since the stores are dynamic and it changes if i change the location how do i update the particular stores website into the url?? @Ram kiran...

Comment: whenever you are setting values to the listview, then make sure that you are storing the those department urls in a separate array

Comment: Hi i did the above but now the problem is that some of the stores such as big bazzar and more. are not displaying the websites bcoz the individual stores dnt have a website i think how can i display the parent website.